# Can I use .includes() or .contains() or .indexOf() when searching through react props in a styled component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I have an instance of a react component with a prop containing an array of strings, like so:

```
<Keyboard notes={['cp', 'dma', 'ema', 'fp', 'gp', 'ama', 'bma']}/>
```

The intention of the component is to create a piano keyboard and invoke it anywhere in the app I'm building, pass in an array of note names, and then all of those notes will be colored differently according to what I have requested via the string for each note. So, I am trying to create a component that will help me avoid making literally thousands of images of a keyboard for every possible state that a piano keyboard could be in.

In a styled component that belongs to the main `Keyboard` component I am passing the prop to it and trying to conditionally change the background color if an array element exists, like so:

```
const C1 = styled.div`
  ${WhiteKey}
  ${props =>
    // tried this:
    props.notes.contains('cp') ? css`${PerfectKey}` :
    // and this:
    (props.notes.contains('cp')) ? css`${PerfectKey}` :
    css`${UnselectedWhiteKey}`
  }
`
```

...which is then used in a react functional component in the same file, like so:

```
const Keyboard = (props) => {

  return (
    <Container>
      <KeyboardBox>
        <WhiteKeys>
          <C1 {...props}></C1>
          <D1 {...props}></D1>
          <E1 {...props}></E1>
          <F1 {...props}></F1>
          <G1 {...props}></G1>
          <A1 {...props}></A1>
          <B1 {...props}></B1>
        </WhiteKeys>
        <BlackKeys>
          <Db1 {...props}></Db1>
          <Eb1 {...props}></Eb1>
          <Gb1 {...props}></Gb1>
          <Ab1 {...props}></Ab1>
          <Bb1 {...props}></Bb1>
        </BlackKeys>
      </KeyboardBox>
    </Container>
  )
}
```

...where each note is it's own styled-component that is trying to look into the array in the prop on it's parent component and decide whether it needs to do something or not.

...but I'm getting the following error message on the page:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'contains' of undefined
```

I tried `indexOf` as well and the same thing happened.

I also tried converting the array into a string, like so:

```
<Keyboard scale={'cp dma ema fp gp ama bma'}/>
```

...and then using `props.scale.includes('cp')` but the same error message again?

What am I doing wrong and is there a more correct and better way to go about conditionally changing css attributes based upon part of the value of a prop, not the whole value?

Or is this a bug and these array methods should work, or is it a lack of a feature that I would find very useful? I don't personally know, so please help if possible. If I can make this work then I will be very happy indeed :-)

here is a minimal reproduction in a code sandbox...trying to make it more minimal, but it is something:

https://codesandbox.io/s/keyboard-3u6ci

Comment: Your styled component is called `C1`, not `Keyboard`. Are you passing the `scale` prop on to your `<C1 />`?

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, @rickdenhaan, edited the question to include the parent component as well, but yes, I pass the prop down to the child via the spread operator.

Comment: I am working on a minimal reproduction currently @EmileBergeron...

Comment: Yes, please check that you are actually passing `scale`/`notes` correctly to each note component. That error implies that either of those props you're trying to access are not defined. You can always define required propTypes, i.e. (`C1.propTypes = { notes: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string).isRequired }` to at least get an error if a `notes` prop is not passed. Or define default props to at least provide a defined array value, i.e. `C1.defaultProps = { notes: [] }`, to check `contains`, etc.

Comment: ok, so i made a code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/keyboard-3u6ci  .... It's still not as minimal as it could probably be, but i keep running into a weird thing where the formatting get messed up when i save it...it does some bizarre things, so trying to figure that out...I added the propType thing and I'm not seeing anything pop up associated with that, so not sure if it's correct or not, but now the error has changed to `TypeError: props.scale.contains is not a function`, soooo...progress?

Comment: ah, ok, I think I have figured out my mistakes...first one, which i totally missed or spaced on, was adding an empty array to my initial state, which i think i filled in subconsciously when creating the minimal reproduction. My second mistake was getting my string and array methods mixed up, as I had it backwards...contains for strings and includes for arrays, not the opposite. So, with those two fixes...in many places...things seem to be working ok now...i was worried that styled-components could not do this, but i am constantly surprised by how awesome they are :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I have figured out my mistakes...first one, which i totally missed or spaced on, was adding an empty array to my initial state, which i think i filled in subconsciously when creating the minimal reproduction. My second mistake was getting my string and array methods mixed up, as I had it backwards...contains for strings and includes for arrays, not the opposite. So, with those two fixes...in many places...things seem to be working ok now...i was worried that styled-components could not do this, but i am constantly surprised by how awesome they are :-)

Thank you for your help @rickdenhann and @emilebergeron and @drewreece